# How do I know which promise will resolve first?

Tags: javascript, promise

I have a snippet that I'm playing around with where I've purposely placed `Promise.resolve(c)` before `Promise.resolve(a)` but I am noticing that the `true` value from bottom `Promise.all(...)` is being logged first.

```
const https = require('https');

function getData(substr) {
    let url = ``;
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            https.get(url, res => {
                let s = '';
                res.on('data', (d) => {
                    s += d
                });

                res.on('end', () => {
                    let data = JSON.parse(s);
                    resolve(data);
                })
            })
        } catch (e) {
            reject(e);
        }
    })
}

let a = getData('spiderman');

let b;

let c = getData('superman');

Promise.resolve(c)
    .then(value => console.log(value));

Promise.resolve(a)
    .then(value => b = value);

Promise.all([a]).then(values => console.log(values[0] === b));
```

Is there any explanation as to why this is the case? I would think that since `Promise.resolve(c)` comes first, that the `Promise c` would resolve first and be logged. Or is there no way to actually rely on the order of the logs aside from using callbacks? What are the best practices to avoid such issues?

Comment: Adding to other points: Since you already return a full-fledged `promise` from `getData(param)` with `reject/resolve` this is really not needed `Promise.resolve(c).then(...)`. It could've been simply `c.then(...)`

Comment: And yes apart from `callbacks` pattern you can also rely on **1.** `async/await` for promises to maintain the order of execution **2.** Chaining/Inside `.then` one after the other (depends on use case and functioning) if need be.

Answer (score 4):

These are asynchronous calls that on complete resolve using the supplied function passed into then.

There is no way to force one of these to finish before and if you need that you should be running these synchronous.

When you call .then() this only gets called when the function finished not when the .resolve gets called.

Comment: ahh I see, that completely makes sense. thanks a lot for the input!

Answer (score 2):

Promise resolution order is not guaranteed.  That's kinda the point of asynchronous code.

If you rely on order of execution, you should be using synchronous code.

Comment: That's a fair point. I guess I was just trying to figure out if there's any way to keep track of Promises **without** the use of `then(...)` but I guess that's why it exist.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Promise.all()` with both requests if you want them both completed before you do your next step.

```
let a = getData('spiderman');

let c = getData('superman');

Promise.all([a, c]).then(([spidyResults, superResults]) => {
    // both have sompleted
    // do stuff with each set of results

}).catch(err => console.log('Ooops, one of them failed') );
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, as said before, the order of the promise completion is not guaranteed, because it's an async operation.

If you really need the execution to follow a certain order you need to put the the next thing to be executed inside `then` or use `async` and `await` which is much cleaner.